# How to hyperlink with myST substitute

Tags: hyperlink, markdown, python-sphinx, myst

I am building documentation of my project using Sphinx, Doxygen and CMake.

In my project, there are several markdown files where I have to hyperlink different links. There is a common style in these links, they are from a common source.

```
https://common/source/html/a.html
https://common/source/html/b.html
https://common/source/html/c.html
```

So, right now I am hyperlinking as like as follows:

```
[This is a](https://common/source/html/a.html)
[This is b](https://common/source/html/b.html)
[This is c](https://common/source/html/c.html)
```

My desire is to use a variable which will hold this common addres `https://common/source/html/` and then I can just modify the previous code snippet as lie as follows:

```
[This is a](COMMON_ADDRESSa.html)
[This is b](COMMON_ADDRESSb.html)
[This is c](COMMON_ADDRESSc.html)
```

I have gone through myST docs and git issue and find some approached but failed

- [Approach 1](https://github.com/executablebooks/MyST-Parser/issues/279#issuecomment-752948379)
  Here, in sphinx's `conf.py`I have added

```py
myst_enable_extensions = [
    # ...
    'substitution'
]

myst_substitutions = {
 "a_link": f"[TARGET NAME](https://common/source/html/)",
}
```

This takes me to `index.html` if I add in my markdown file `{{a_link}}`. But my desire is to concatenate html files from markdown file and have no idea how to do it. I have tried `{{a_link}}/a.html` but it does not work.

- [Approach 2](https://myst-parser.readthedocs.io/en/stable/syntax/optional.html#substitutions-and-urls)
  Here also the target name and complete link address is written. No way to concatenate link address is described
- I have also tried to replace common address by using `rst_prolog` which is also failed

I guess that I am not understanding how the hyperlinking process is working in markdown file.

So, I am searching for a way where I can parse the long address which will be assigned in a variable and can concatenate required html file name with it to perform hyperlinking.

Comment: Use [`myst_url_schemes`](https://myst-parser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/syntax/cross-referencing.html#customising-external-url-resolution). If you cannot use v0.19 or later, then use the Sphinx extension [`sphinx.ext.extlinks`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/extlinks.html).